# How can I convert this code to return matches in array by substring?

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following array:

```
arr = ["lol","test"]
```

and a code:

```
matches = content.downcase.split & arr
```

where `content` is a string. This code returns `["lol"]` when `content = "Something lol"`, but fails to return anything when `content = "Something #lol."` with a comma or hashtag etc. It always fails when there is no exact match.

I'd like to match with the strings in the array as substring. How can this be done by adapting the above code?

Comment: Does "lol"  in `arr` match "Something xlolx"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting on non-word boundary as shown below

```
arr = ["lol","test"]

content = "Something #lol."
p matches = content.downcase.split(/\W/) & arr
```

Outputs

```
["lol"]
```

Sample runs from [Try ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) is shown below

[image]

Comment: What you mean it fails ?  Can you please let me what you see?  I updated my answer with output I see

Comment: simply does not match and returns empty

Answer (score 1):

Not efficient, but this works:

```
matches = content.downcase.split.select{|s| arr.any?{|_s| s.include?(_s)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what kind of results you want to receive. I think you can use `String#scan`. It will return an array of matched data:

```
patterns = ["lol","test"]
data = content.downcase
matches = patterns.flat_map { |pattern| data.scan(pattern) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = content.downcase
arr.select { |w| s =~ /\b#{w}\b/ }
```